# MinGW-w64 Thread Creation Failure

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11

**resolution: pass "-static" in miscellanious linker options**
---OR---
**resolution: Download this MinGW-Version http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/?source=dlp**

I am using Eclipse with the MinGW-w64 Toolchain. My GCC version is 4.8

I want to create a application that consists out of 2 Threads. I've allready tried to implement this into my actually application. Thus it didnt work i decided to make a new test app.

**Source(main.cpp):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void test() {
     cout << "works.." << endl;
}

int main() {

    thread t(test);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**Build Process:**

```
21:19:51 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Test ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=gnu++11 -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: Test.exe
Invoking: MinGW C++ Linker
g++  -o "Test.exe"  ./main.o   -lpthread -lwinpthread -pthread -lpthread
Finished building target: Test.exe


21:19:53 Build Finished (took 1s.863ms)
```

When running i get the following error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

btw: the many -pthread etc. commands come from a couple of trys to make it work.
im running win vista 32 bit

I really appreciate if some one knows how to resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try *compiling* with the `-pthread` flag.

Comment: Whose distro are you using?

Comment: @n.mthats my point i've added those flags everywhere i can insert any flag^^ in gcc c++ compiler and mingw c++ linker

Comment: @Rapptz Eclipse Juno  4.2.2

Comment: Some `MinGW-w64` builds support `<thread>` and some don't. Did you build yourself, or where did you get the build? Also, you shouldn't being passing those flags if you are on vista.

Comment: I don't see `-pthread` in your compilation line. You **have** to use it, not `-lpthread`, `-lwinpthread` or anything else. `-l*` flags are for linking and they should still be used in your link line.

Comment: @n.m. It's irrelevant. You don't need to pass it for some distros. This is MinGW, not GCC on Linux. OP's issue is most likely that it doesn't support `std::thread`.

Comment: @JesseGood ok, i have tried mingw-w64 4.7 and mingw-w64 4.8, both with the same results. But i didnt knew i shoudnt use flags on vista, so how can i get my compiler to compile this test app without errors?

Comment: @Rapptz gcc -v says: "Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 20130324 (prerelease) (rubenvb-4.8-stdthread)"

Comment: @user1946282 Try passing `-static`.

Comment: @user1946282: You can [also try the builds here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) they should work without passing `-static`.

Comment: @JesseGood Ruben's updated build doesn't require passing `-static`, he told me it was an oversight.

Comment: @JesseGood where are the includefiles for gcc in this package?

Comment: @user1946282: They should be all under `x86_64-w64-mingw32` (the layout is different from rubenvb's builds).

Comment: @JesseGood there are only c - includes

Comment: @user1946282: They should be `mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++` or something similar (I hadn't used the builds in a while so I had to check).

Comment: @JesseGood is it possible that this is only for 64Bit? b/c i  cant execute a single exe, and folders are called x86_64

Comment: @user1946282: Did you click the [32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/) folder? You should see something like `host-windows / releases / 4.8.0 / 32-bit / threads-win32` as the path.

Comment: @Rapptz wich is the updated one?

Comment: @user1946282 http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-experimental-stdthread/

Comment: @Rapptz thx already have the 32bit of this, need to use "static-libstdc++" for this

Answer (score 0):

See here for native win32 std::thread implementation that can be added to any C++11 version of MinGW:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads